# Can a dropper post be added to a Giant bicycle with D-Fuse?

Tags: seatpost, gravel, giant, dropper, seattube

I just bought a Giant Revolt that comes with a D-Fuse seat post. I really hate this mechanism, I have to remove the seat frequently to store the bike. I was wondering if it's possible to change to a dropper post like a mountain bike?

Answer (score 4):

[This site](https://www.bikeradar.com/reviews/bikes/gravel-bikes/2022-giant-revolt-advanced-pro-0/#:%7E:text=The%20seatpost%20fitting%2C%20however%2C%20is,want%20to%20change%20things%20up.)  says the Revolt Advanced Pro 0 has a 30.9mm seatpost and can take a MTB dropper. Key thing is that the frame takes a standard round post and you can find a dropper of the correct diameter - 30.9 is common.

You will need check for your frame.

Comment: But what about the actuation mechanism? Does this bicycle have a hole for internal dropper cable routing? If not, then the dropper post options are limited to either an externally routed one, or a wirelessly actuated one.

Comment: I was under the impression that D-Fuse seatposts were D shaped. Round post no fit hole.

Comment: @GrigoryRechistov externally actuated dropper posts are common. The last post I fitted was internal and I drilled a hole in the frame. This is fine when done correctly.

Comment: @Noise The post has D shape but inside the frame there is a shim to make it round

Comment: @Grigory - While now not as common as they once were (in the early days no one had holes in frames for droppers) ), externally routed droppers are available.